# Disappearing Content

Tags: security, nodes

I just inherited a Drupal 7 website from another agency. The site was fairing well in our DEV and STAGE environments. The problem started occurring when we switched DNS over to our PRODUCTION site.

We have all the nodes (from the same content type) that seem to be "randomly" disappearing.

I've made sure to upgrade the core to the latest and any security fixes for any modules that are being used.

I was wondering what I could do to troubleshoot this issue - as I'm exhausting all my efforts and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache and rebuilding the node permissions? if you are login to your site would you still have the problem with those?

Comment: define randomly disappearing please. are those nodes deleted? or just showing 404s sometimes?

Comment: The nodes were deleted from a non-drupal related script. I'll make sure to post a follow up answer to this question. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a cache problem. I will suggest to do this, as usual backup is always a good idea:

1. See if this happens also if you are login. You might have your node permissions corrupted. If you rebuild and have a lot of node, it might take a little while to do this.
2. Turning cache off for page and blocks.
3. is your content generated by a view? if so check the permission

Comment: I found the issue. It was previous agency-related code that was running from an external source on a cron job hitting this script.

    function drop_villas() {
        $result = db_query("SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = 'villa'");
        foreach ($result as $n) {
     node_delete($n->nid);
        }
    }

Needless to say - the offending agency isn't very professional about transitioning this site.

Comment: can you answer your question and mark as accepted later. It will help our community.

Answer (score -3):

Local module is disabled. Enable the Local module. It will solve it.

Comment: The correct answer was added as a comment by the OP about a year ago. Downvoted, as this answer does not make sense.